# Call smart contract function from another smart contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I am new to Solidity and I'm having some trouble when calling a function of a smart contract from another one.

Basically I have smart contract A, which extends ERC20 and the Ownable contract from openzeppelin.

```
contract contractA is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
    }

    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        _mint(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Then I have smart contract B:

```
contract contractB is Ownable {
  address contract_a;

  constructor(address contract_address) {
    contract_a = account;
  }

  function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = contract_a.call(
      abi.encodeWithSignature("mint(address,uint256)", account, amount)
    );

    require(success, "call failed");
  }
}
```

Both smart contracts are being deployed by the same user address, and I want that to be the owner of both smart contracts. I firstly deploy contractA, and then deploy contractB using the contractA's address.

When calling the `mint` function in contractB, `success` is always false, and I have no idea why this is failing. If I remove the `onlyOwner` from the `mint` function in contractA it starts working, so I believe it has something to do with this.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of the call from `contractB` to `contractA` as an additional "internal transaction", so it still has to adhere to the rules of `contractA`. In other words, since your `mint` function can only be called by the owner, and the owner of `contractA` is not `contractB`, the transaction fails.

To remedy this, you could create your own modifier that checks if the caller (`msg.sender`) is either the owner or `contractB`.

More specifically, the `onlyOwner` modifier checks that `msg.sender` is the owner, and `msg.sender` is the address of the calling account, which in your case is the address of `contractB`, not the address that signed the original transaction.

Comment: But, wouldn't the `call` method pass the same msg.sender? Or is there a way of passing that information to contractA, in a way that `onlyOwner` is truthy?

Comment: No, `msg.sender` is the caller of the contract, not (necessarily) the signer of the transaction. For your example `msg.sender` is the address of your account in `contractB`, but `msg.sender` in `contractA` is the address of `contractB`. Likewise, if `contractA` called `contractX`, `msg.sender` in `contractX` would be the address of `contractA`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you!!